# I have difficulty in normalise my vector by using open gl

Tags: opengl, glm-math

I am trying to normalise the vector by calling glm::vec3(x,y,z) =  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(x,y,z)) but when I print the new x,y,z they seems not correct since some values bigger than 1

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
glm::vec3(x,y,z) = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(x,y,z));
```

you are creating a temporary and assignint to it the results of normalization. At the end of instruction, the temporary will be deleted.

In order to this to work, try something like this:

```
glm::vec3 v = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(x,y,z));
```

and look for values in `v.x`, `v.y`, and `v.z`